# A conjectured trace inequality for some products of powers of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B, R\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ hermitian and $B$ positive semidefinite.
Let $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s,t \ge 0$ .

Does then hold $Tr[B^s (B R^2 B)^t] \ge Tr[B^s (R B^2 R)^t]$ ?

Comment: Can you clarify what it means to raise a matrix to a real power?

Comment: $B$, $B R^2 B$ and $R B^2 R$ are all positive semidefinite. Therefore the positive real power is well defined for these matices .

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Are you sure? I think I can prove it in the t=1 case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the inequality is false. Consider for instance the choices

\begin{equation*}
B = \begin{bmatrix} 5&     6&    -2\\
     6  &  13  &   2\\
    -2  &   2  &   5\end{bmatrix},\quad
R = \begin{bmatrix}
 -8  &   4  &   4\\
     4 &   -2 &   -1\\
     4 &   -1 &    0   
    \end{bmatrix},\quad s=5,\ t=3.
\end{equation*}
Then, we have (computed using Mathematica)

> lhs = Tr[MatrixPower[b, s].MatrixPower[b.r.r.b, t]]

which yields **415274500333934**, whereas

> rhs = Tr[MatrixPower[b, s].MatrixPower[r.b.b.r, t]]

yields **450223588494254**, so that lhs-rhs = **-34949088160320**.

Comment: Do you have also a counterexample for $t \le 2$ ?

Comment: Could you verify that $B=\{\{12,-4, 0\},\{-4, 2, 2\},\{0, 2, 8\}\}$ and $R=\{\{-2, -3 ,-2\},\{-3 ,-7,-3\},\{-2, -3, 3\}\}$ for $s=9$ and $t=7/4$ yields a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, this is also a counterexample. Next interesting case is $t = 1/2$ .

Comment: seems like $0\le t \le 1/2$ could hold, though not yet fully sure. Perhaps the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00853 sparks some ideas....