# A conjectured trace inequality for some products of powers of matrices II

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B, R\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ hermitian and $B$ positive semidefinite.
Let $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s \ge 0$ .

Does then hold $Tr[B^s (I + B R^2 B)^{-1}] \le Tr[B^s (I + R B^2 R)^{-1}]$ ?

See also [A conjectured trace inequality for some products of powers of matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278540/a-conjectured-trace-inequality-for-some-products-of-powers-of-matrices) .